# WIndows 2008 intrusion detection

Tags: windows-server-2008, security

Are there any recommendations for an IDS and other critical security services for a Windows 2008 webserver?

Comment: What "other critical security services" are you referring to?

Comment: malware, virus software

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [OSSEC HIDS](http://www.ossec.net/) that can monitor logs, changes on the filesystem and registry keys.

OSSEC can work as a standalone software (just one server) or reporting to a central manager. There is a web UI and you can also [manage alerts](http://www.splunkbase.com/apps/All/4.x/App/app:Splunk+for+OSSEC+(Splunk+v4+version)) with  [Splunk](http://www.splunk.com).

If you want to add up more security services, you can integrate OSSEC alerts into [OSSIM](http://www.ossim.net) and get other security features such as vulnerability management or correlation.

Comment: appears you still need a linux server to manage any windows agents?

Answer (score 2):

You haven't specified whether you are looking for a [HIDS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Host-based_intrusion_detection_system) or [NIDS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_intrusion_detection_system), so I've assumed the former - [Verisys](http://www.ionx.co.uk) is a file integrity monitoring system for Windows that should fit in with the rest of your security (antivirus, firewalls etc). For example, you can use it to detect any changes to critical system files or web pages.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend OSSEC http://www.ossec.net/

OSSEC is an Open Source Host-based Intrusion Detection System. It performs log analysis, file integrity checking, policy monitoring, rootkit detection, real-time alerting and active response.

Regards
D

Answer (score 0):

Looking for software based on the windows box, or an external device?

If external look at SonicWALL, or Barracuda's Web App Firewall:

http://www.barracudanetworks.com/ns/products/web-site-firewall-overview.php

SonicWALLs are typically more higher end than the Barracudas.